# How to use useState with {}?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

given this..

`const [question, setQuestion] = useState({})`

and `question` can contain a title and a description.

I.E.

```
{ 
  title: 'How to use useState with {}?', 
  decription: 'given this..`const [question, setQuestion] = useState({})`and `question` can contain a title and a description. I.E.    {       title: 'How to use useState with {}?',       decription: ''     }How can the title and description be set independently with `setQuestion`?'
 }
```

How can the title and description be set independently with `setQuestion`?

Comment: If you want to set them separately, why not split the state? It's part of the benefits of `useState`

Answer (score 4):

The setter function you get from `useState()` expects to be passed argument which will entirely replace the old state. So you can't use it to update just the title, without also passing in all other properties.

But you can derive a new state object from the existing one and then pass that whole object to `setQuestion()`

```
setQuestion({
   ...question,
   title: "New title",
})
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I like to do in this situation is to use the `React.useReducer` hook instead:

```js
function App() {
  const initialState = { 
    title: 'My title',  
    description: 'My description'
  }
  const [state, setState] = React.useReducer(
    (p, n) => ({ ...p, ...n }),
    initialState
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{state.title}</p>
      <p>{state.description}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setState({ description: 'New description' })}>
        Set new description
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way, you're only changing the properties that you want and don't have to deal with copying the old state object and creating a new one based on old and new values.

Also, it will probably look more familiar to you if you're just starting with `hook`s because of the similarity to the `this.setState()` calls inside class components.

Here's a little example that shows this approach in action:

- [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-wing-9fivt?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a common pattern you use then I'd suggest writing your own hook to implement the functionality you want.

If it's a one-off thing then you can use the object spread operator to do it fairly cleanly:

```
setQuestion({
  ...question,
  title: 'updated title',
});
```

Here is what it would look like pulled out into a separate hook:

```
const useMergeState = (initial) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initial);
  const mergeState = React.useCallback((update) => setState({...state, ...update}));
  return [state, mergeState];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The [official Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) says:

> Both putting all state in a single useState call, and having a
>   useState call per each field can work. However, **components tend to be most
>   readable when you find a balance between these two extremes**, and group
>   related state into a few independent state variables.

Eg:

```
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ left: 0, top: 0 });
  const [size, setSize] = useState({ width: 100, height: 100 });
```

> In case the state logic becomes complex, we recommend managing it with a **reducer** or a **custom Hook**.

Also, remember in case you are using any state object in the **useState({})** hook, that unlike the classic **this.setState**, *updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it*, so you need to spread the previous state in order not to lose some of his properties eg:  `setResource(…resource, name: ‘newName’);`

Answer (score 0):

```
setQuestion({
  title: 'YOUR_TITLE',
  description: 'YOUR_DESCRIPTION',
  id: '13516',
})
```

State cannot be edited. You need to set new value always. Thus, it can be replaced with [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as below.

```js
setQuestion({
  ...question,
  title: 'new title'
})
```

or

```
const newQuestion = { ...question, title: 'new title }
setQuestion(newQuestion)
```